# Method call is ambigous with varargs operator

Tags: java, overloading, variadic-functions, scjp

The code below produces the syntax error:

> The method `f(int[])` is ambiguous for the type C

My code:

```
public class C{

    public static void f(int... i)
    {
        System.out.println("a");
    }

    public static void f(Integer... i)
    {
        System.out.println("b");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        f(new Integer(2));
    }
}
```

If I use array notation `[]` instead of the `...` and call the function properly with `f(new Integer[]{3,4,5})`, the compiler can correctly decide which method do I want to use.

What is the reason the compiler cannot decide which function to call with `...`?

Comment: I know what autoboxing means but I don't really see how it works in this context. Care to explain?

Comment: definitely will show error at compile time ... you should have atleast 1 argument for varialbe number of arguements. declare f as f(int j , int... i).  Second issue is with boxing and autoboxing. Which u can explore here at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html

Comment: Should  compile fine as method signatures are different and byte code is different. But passing a single int or an array of int,  by boxing rules both the methods become eligible for use thus the error. If you array [] in args of one method then that method cannot take varargs. Note that int[] and Integer[] are two different things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The process of finding the "right" method for a specific invocation site is explained in [JLS, Secion 15.12, "Method Invocation Expressions"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12). After a short prelude with basic sanity checks, the relevant part starts at [section 15.12.2.1, Identify Potentially Applicable Methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.1). In your case, both methods are *potentially applicable*, according to this definition.

The subsequent process consists of three phases. In your case, the method is a *variable arity* method (due to the "varargs"). So it immediately starts at [15.12.2.4, Phase 3: Identify Applicable Variable Arity Methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.4).

> The method m is an applicable variable-arity method if and only if all of the following conditions hold:
>
> - For 1 ≤ i < n, the type of ei, Ai, can be converted by method invocation conversion to Si.
> - ...

(the other conditions are not relevant here)

The [Method Invocation Conversion (JLS, 5.3)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.3) allows for the following conversions:

- an identity conversion (§5.1.1)
- a widening primitive conversion (§5.1.2)
- a widening reference conversion (§5.1.5)
- a boxing conversion (§5.1.7) optionally followed by widening reference conversion
- an unboxing conversion (§5.1.8) optionally followed by a widening primitive conversion.

The conversion from `Integer` to `Integer` is an identity conversion (first bullet point). The conversion from `Integer` to `int` is a unboxing conversion (last bullet point).

So both methods are "applicable variable arity methods" according to the specification.

Answer (score 0):

The rule is `WBV/WAV` **Widening - > (Auto)Boxing - > Varargs** in case of *Method Overloading*.

1. Widening

   ```
   int -> long -> float -> double
   ```
2. Boxing

   ```
   Integer -> Number -> Object
   ```
3. a) Widening then Varargs

   ```
   int... -> long... -> float... -> double...
   ```

   b) Boxing then Varargs

   ```
   Integer... -> Number... -> Object...
   ```

---

In another words

```
   Varargs  [Last option]
      ^
      |
   Boxing   [Newer style, added in Java 1.5]
      ^
      |
   Widening [Older style, choosen by the compiler to support existing code]
```

---

**Note:**

- `Boxing` then `Widening` is allowed as well.
- `Varargs` then `Boxing` is not allowed.
- `Varargs` is treated as last option between `Widening` and `boxing`
- Chooses either `Widening then Varargs` or `Boxing then Varargs`. If both the  possibilities are present then results into **ambiguous** method call.

---

The conversion in your case of `f(new Integer(2))`. As per rule `Boxing` then `Widening`

```
Integer -> Number -> Object -> int -> long -> float -> double
```

Now there are 2 possibilities next to `double`

- 3.a) Widening then Varargs (`int...`)
- 3.b) Boxing then Varargs (`Integer...`)

but both are present hence result into  **ambiguous** method call.

---

The conversion in your case of `f(new Integer[]{3,4,5})`

`Integer...` is direct match. `Varargs` then `Boxing` is not allowed.

Comment: I'm not sure whether this is what you meant, but ... the process of finding applicable varargs methods is completely separated from the process of finding applicable matching arity methods. When a method is a varargs method, then method invocation conversions can be applied to all its arguments.

Answer (score 0):

`Varargs` and `Boxing` were both introduced in Java 5 onwards.With Java 5 came issues of dealing with legacy code where the compiler performed widening operation(for example where there is long,the compiler will choose long over Integer,since widening operation from int to long was allowed before Java 5),but since varargs and Boxing are on the same level(Java 5 onwards) the compiler is unable to determine the correct type.Just remove varargs and replace with an array,it would work fine

**There is no defined preference between Varargs and Boxing/Unboxing when they are used in combination**

Comment: `Varargs` is always considered as last option. In case of `Boxing` and `Varargs` the `Boxing` wins.

Comment: @user3218114 Reason compiler doesnt choose int... is that you have to first unbox with Integer[2] followed with a varargs invocation

Answer (score -2):

The ... is meant for variable number of arguments. You have to pass the values like f(1, 2, 3) and that is the reason for the error.

Comment: Nope, the ... operator also accepts single values as argument. The error message is the same with multiple values.